# How can I set the height of a UITextView to exactly match its truncated content?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` whose height I would like to limit to some reasonable value, with the text truncating if necessary. How can I make sure that the height of the text view matches that of the *truncated* content? If, for example, I set the height to a fixed value, there will some variable space at the bottom of the text view which will affect the layout of items below it.

[image]

Is there some way to set a desired height, measure the truncated text, and then use that measurement to more precisely adjust the height? Is there even a way to measure the height of the *displayed* text within the `UITextView`?

**Edit**

I need to clarify:

1. I do not need help truncating the text. As you can see from the screenshot, the text is truncated already.
2. I cannot measure the text because I would need to measure the the `truncated` text, which I don't have access to.
3. The gap at the bottom of the text view is not related to the `textcontainerInset`.

This is how the screenshot is currently built:

1. The text is set to some long string.
2. The text view is artificially constrained to some height, let's say `300`. This produces the truncation.
3. Because `300` is not a precise multiple of the line height, there is some additional space below the last truncated line.

What I would like to do:

After sizing the text view to `300`, measure the precise height of the **truncated** text so that I can then resize the text view a second time to fit it without the additional spacing (e.g. set it to `285` if that is the measured size).

Or, some other method to achieve the same end result.

Comment: If you really want help, why not post a downloadable project that shows exactly what you’re doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect it's truncated because of your constraints. So you need to calculate the text size in the code and update the constraint value:

```
let boundingRect = (textView.text as NSString).boundingRect(
    with: maxSize,
    options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
    attributes: [ .font: textView.font ],
    context: nil
)
heightConstraint.constant = boundingRect.height.rounded(.up)
```

The result of this operation is float and not related to pixels. When the view size is calculated by the constraints, it get's rounded to pixels (0.5 or 0.333...), that's why we need to round it by ourself to exclude unpredictable cases. To get pixel perfect height you can round it according to screen scale:

```
textViewHeightConstraint.constant = (boundingRect.height * UIScreen.main.nativeScale).rounded(.up) / UIScreen.main.nativeScale
```

Also, as @nghiahoang mentioned below, don't forget to zero the insets

```
textView.textContainerInset = .zero
```

Here's my [sample project](https://github.com/PhilipDukhov/TruncatedTestViewTest)

Comment: I want it to be truncated. I want to size the text view to exactly match the truncated height.

Comment: @BenPackard sure, you just specify max width and height in maxSize, and it'll be truncated

Comment: Right, but my question isn't 'How can I truncate the text' (which is already present in my screenshot). It is how to then size the text view to match that truncated text - in other words, removing the are marked in red.

Comment: @BenPackard how do you truncate it? Default implementation doesn't do it, so sample code will be helpful. Basically the code I've added as an answer will calculate the size of your text.

Comment: A text view is truncated by disabling scrolling. After that it is automatic, so long as the text is larger than the view. The problem is how to know the physical size of that text once it has been truncated, since the text view is responsible for it, not me. Therefore I don't have a truncated string to measure.

Comment: @BenPackard I've added an edit to support multiline text size calculation, as well as a sample project

Comment: I don't think my questions is clear enough since this doesn't really answer it. I am going to add an edit.

Comment: @BenPackard in my sample project it's exactly the same. I have one constraint that's limiting the width, so I use textView width as a max width, and I'm using constant as a max height, to calculate text size and update the height constraints. If your case is not the same, please create a pull request to my sample project so I can check it out

Comment: Simply bump your font size up to 20 and run on the iPhone SE simulator. You will see the same issue - https://imgur.com/cdwKAYp

Comment: @BenPackard my bad, I forget to round the value. I've updated the answer with more info

Comment: But you are still measuring the size of the entire text, not the truncated text. Is your sample project updated? If so I can try it again if you like.

Comment: @BenPackard yes, it's updated, check it out. By limiting the size of bounding rect we're achieving the same result as the textView when it's truncating it

Answer (score 0):

Compile the solution of Philip and set the inset.bottom to 0

```
textView.textContainerInset.bottom = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Directly, it is not possible. If you want to do it, you have take `UILabel` behind the `UITextView`. Because `UILabel` has the property to auto extend the height and width based on text. Now. set equal constraints of `UILabel` to `UItextview`.
what should be constraints, let me explore step by step :

1. set leading and trailing of `UILabel`.
2. Fix top constraints of `uILabel`.
3. you not need to set height constraint but if you want, you can set greater than equal to constraint of constant 20 or 30.
4. Now set leading, trailing,top and height constraints of UITextview equal to UILabel.

Now whatever you set text in `UIlabel` , give it to label as well. I did not in past. If you will find any issue please ask in comment

Comment: If you do not set a height constraint on the label, how will it truncate the text?